# Reload the page after Instabot sends a message using Flask

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

I am currently creating a web page with Jquery and Flask. I am sending inputs from ajax and get input values in Flask. When Flask receives the values, a module, Instabot, sends a message. I would like to automatically reload the page after Instabot sends a message.

I tried to reload the page in form.js but then the input values are not sent to a DM. I also tried to redirect the page 'index.html' by using `redirect('index.html'), render_template('index.html'), redirect(url_for('index.html'))`. Yet, those are not working.

This is `index.html`

```
<form class="form-inline">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input style="text-align-last: center;" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6 mt-3 mt-md-0">
            <div style="position: relative;"><input style="background: white; text-align-last: center;" type="text" class="form-control"  id="datetimepicker" placeholder="Pick Date and Time"></div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
        <br>
     <div class="text-center"><button id="submit_button" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send Message</button></div>
 </form>
```

Here is `form.js` for ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 flatpickr("#datetimepicker", 
{
  enableTime: true,
  dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i K",
  minDate: "today",
  disableMobile: "true"
});

$('form').on('submit',function(event) {
var name = $('#name').val();
var datetime = $("#datetimepicker").val();
  $.ajax({
    data: {
      name: name,
      datetime: datetime
    },
    url: '/contact',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) {
      if(data.error) {
        alert('Error!');
      } else {
        location.reload(); // this is what I tried
      }
    }
  });
event.preventDefault();});});
```

This is `contact.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, send_from_directory, 
   redirect, url_for
from instabot import Bot import os 
import glob
import time

 bot = Bot()

 app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')

 @app.route('/')
 def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

 @app.route('/contact', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
 def contact():
   name = request.form['name']
   datetime = request.form['datetime']

# Login using bot.
bot.login(username="myInstaID",
         password="myInstaPW", is_threaded=True)
urer_ids = "Friend's InstaID"

text = "New Appointment: \n Name: {} \n Date: {}".format(name, datetime)
# Sending messages

bot.send_messages(text, urer_ids)
return redirect('/') // this is I tried to solve my issue
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

I am stuck here for a month. I have no idea. Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: your code in `contact.py` has wrong indentations - so it useless for us. OR it can make problems.

Comment: maybe in JavaScript you should use `console.log` (or `alert()`) to see what you really get in `success: function()` - as for me `def contact()` should return some `data`  for your `success: function()` instead of redirect - and maybe then it will work `location.reload()`

Comment: `AJAX` was invented to send request without reloading page. When Python runs `redirect()` then it sends this information to `AJAX` and it stops reloading page. Only AJAX can reload page when it sends request to server. And you should check what you have in `data.error` because it may stops code to run `location.reload()`. OR simply send `form` in normal way - without using `ajax`